# Generic Powerpoint Developer Controls Value Saving in VBA

Tags: vba, controls, ms-office, powerpoint

I am looking to create a sort of Quiz using Powerpoint and I would like to save the input given by the user.

For example: If I ask the question: What is your favorite color? When they answer the question and click the next button, I would like to save the value of the textbox and append it to an output file.

I already know how to get the value and write the value to a file.

What I am looking to do is a sort of loop.

Here is the pseudo-code:

```
foreach(Control c in CurrentSlide.Controls)
{
     File.Append(c.Value);
}
```

This way, no matter what controls are on the form, I want to save the value of each and every control.

Is this possible in VBA? If not, do you have any generic solutions for this situation?

Comment: Blue.  No! Yel--  Auuuuuuuugh!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a more generic way of checking for each control on the slide, w/o knowing in advance how many there'll be.  This assumes that you've kept the default names assigned to control shapes (TextBox1, CheckBox1 and so on).  If you want to change those, you'll need to be sure that each TextBox has a name that includes at least one bit of string that's unique to it and change the code accordingly.  Siddarth has already supplied code for writing to files and you said you have that under control so I'm just Debug.Printing the values here to keep the example simple.

```
Sub TestIt()
    ' Run this to test the shapes on slide 1
    ProcessTheSlide ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
End Sub

Sub ProcessTheSlide(oSl As Slide)

    Dim oSh As Shape

    For Each oSh In oSl.Shapes
        ' Is it a control?
        If oSh.Type = 12 Then  ' msoOLEControlObject
            On Error Resume Next
            With oSh.OLEFormat.Object
                If InStr(.Name, "TextBox") > 0 Then
                    Debug.Print .Text
                End If
                If InStr(.Name, "CheckBox") > 0 Then
                    Debug.Print .Value
                End If

            End With
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Alright, so I seem to be having some issues. I am using the default controls that are provided in the Powerpoint Developer Tab. They are all ActiveX Controls and it seems they have a type of 1, instead of 12. Can this code be adapted for ActiveX controls?

Comment: As I am looping through the Shapes, if I display the name of each Shape, I am getting things like "Rectangle 1 - 5" and not the names of the controls.

Comment: Nevermind, I found the fix. ProcessTheSlide ActivePresentation.Slides(1) only runs on Slide 1. How do I get this to run on the CURRENT slide?

Comment: You'd call ProcessTheSlide for each slide in your presentation.  The TestIt sub is simply a test routine.  BTW, your other comments make me wonder whether you copied the code as-is or not.

Answer (score 1):

> > > Is this possible in VBA?

Yes it is :)

On your presentation, Place 1 TextBox and two Command Buttons. Your presentation should look like this.

[image]

In the VBA Editor paste this code

```
Option Explicit

'~~> Save data to file
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim filesize As Integer
    Dim FlName As String

    '~~> text File where you want to save the data
    FlName = "C:\Sample.Txt"

    '~~> Get a free file handle
    filesize = FreeFile()

    '~~> Open your file
    Open FlName For Append As #filesize

    '~~> Export Text
    Print #filesize, TextBox1.Text
    Close #filesize

    TextBox1.Text = ""
End Sub

'~~> Exit Show
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    SlideShowWindows(1).View.Exit
End Sub
```

Now when you run it and click on "Next", the data will automatically be saved in the text file.

[image]

And this is how your text file will look...

[image]

HTH